# java, utf8, international characters and byte interpretation

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have a String that gets input to my program.

4 letters A, O, "E with an umlaut", L

The hex code for "E with an umlaut" is 0xc38b.  see [UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x) and look for "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS"

And then it gets weird

My java code is not printing "E with an umlaut" but "A with a ~" followed by 0x8b

When I convert the string to a byte array and the print it out as hex, my 4 character string becomes 7 characters:

```
byte[0]=41 "A"
byte[1]=4f "O"
byte[2]=c3 c383 is "A with a ~" (per above link)
byte[3]=83
byte[4]=c2 c28b is some kind of control character (per above link)
byte[5]=8b
byte[6]=4c "L"
```

I have verified my encoding is UTF-8 via Charset.defaultCharset()

It almost looks like its interpreting the bytes incorrectly but how is that possible?

Can anyone shed any light on why the byte interpretation of this string is getting screwed up and how i can correct it?

Comment: Show the code where you're converting the String. Also the code where the String is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes everything is correct. Those Unicode characters above U+7F, non 7-bits ASCII, are encoded with multiple bytes, like the (Dutch) U+C38B. Every byte of that sequence have there high bit set. In other character sets, like some Windows single-byte character set, that will be two or more weird characters.

```
String s = "Zee\uC38Bn van tijd in Belgi\uC38B\r\n";
Path path = "C:/temp/test.txt";
Files.write(path, ("\uFEFF" + s).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

The above writes a text file with a BOM char (zero width space) at the beginning (U+FEFF). This is an ugly redundancy and helps Windows Notepad to recognize the file as UTF-8.

---

Clarification

The Unicode character U+C38B, in java the java char '\uC38B' is actually `쎋`. That indeed is converted to 4 bytes in UTF-8.

`Ë` actually is  U+CB or `'\u00CB'`. Its byte representation in UTF-8 is as follows:

```
String s = new String(new byte[]{ (byte)0xC3, (byte)0x8B}, 0, 2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

That UTF-8 is something totally different than simply splitting the (sequential) Unicode number for that character serves several purposes: the byte sequence is recognizable as part of a multibyte sequence: start and continuation bytes, and normal ASCII like `/` can never be part of such a byte sequence. So normal ASCII is safe.

Comment: Yes, but he's supposed to get 2 bytes, not 4. It's not UTF-8, it's corrupted.

Comment: @Kayaman I now recognize the mistake. I could have known that C38B never was extended Latin. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Somewhere along the line, your input is encoded with UTF-8, then decoded with ISO 8859-1 (or a similar single-byte encoding). At this point the string is corrupted.

Encoding `"Ë"` with UTF-8 results in the bytes `[ 0xC3 0x8B ]`. Decoding this with ISO 8859-1 produces the corrupt string, `"Ã‹"` (`"\u00C3\u008B"`). Re-encoding that string with UTF-8 produces the byte sequence from the original question, `[ 0xC3 0x83 0xC2 0x8B ]`

Determine where ISO 8859-1 is erroneously used to decode UTF-8 data, and specify UTF-8 instead.

This is a common problem when decoding web requests or responses. Standards specify ISO 8859-1 as the character encoding unless explicitly overridden, so frameworks fall back to this as a default.

Comment: i just want to be clear ... are you saying that its already screwed up at the point i get [ 0xC3 0x83 0xC2 0x8B ]?

Comment: @user1126515 Yes, definitely. Too late to fix there.

Comment: @user1126515 Well in this case you can encode the corrupted `String` with ISO 8859-1 and then decode the resulting bytes with UTF-8 to undo the corruption. But this is a fragile kludge that you could use to recover some data that has been corrupted, not the right way to handle encoding.